# Run python *.py file in prompt of windows doesn't import modules

Tags: python, windows, import, module, command-prompt

I have a file `foo.py` where I import some modules (e.g. progressbar). I can run this file on the Windows 7 command prompt without any problems on one PC (Windows 7 OS without environment variable path setting) but run into problems on another PC (where this module is installed). When I run with the second PC I get this error message:

```
C:\Users>D:\foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    from progressbar import ProgressBar
ImportError: No module named progressbar
```

I tried to follow several posts on stack overflow, setting the environment variable path (e.g., ...;C:\Python27;), etc. but without a real solution.

Comment: Can you tell/show us exactly how you've set the environment variable[s] on the 2nd PC?

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton. My set is ...;C:\Python27;. in the first PC i didn't set nothing and the file can import modules without problem

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "My set is ...;C:\Python27;.". The "..." is not a valid path as far as Windows is concerned. What have you set? How did you set it?

Comment: Are the modules within a package? Could `ProgressBar` be in the sys.path? Also, could it be part of another but in package that you can't access?

Comment: i can run all modules with a simple IDLE but not when i run the *.py with a command prompt